# MySQL SELECT most frequent by group

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, frequency

How do I get the most frequently occurring category for each tag in MySQL? Ideally, I would want to simulate an aggregate function that would calculate the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) of a column.

```
SELECT 
  t.tag 
  , s.category 
FROM tags t 
LEFT JOIN stuff s 
USING (id) 
ORDER BY tag;

+------------------+----------+
| tag              | category |
+------------------+----------+
| automotive       |        8 |
| ba               |        8 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |       10 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        9 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |       10 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| bamboo           |        9 |
| bamboo           |        8 |
| banana tree      |        8 |
| banana tree      |        8 |
| banana tree      |        8 |
| banana tree      |        8 |
| bath             |        9 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Just thought I'd mention a couple years later and smarter - don't organize tags like this, it's an antipattern. Use a many2many table to define the relationship between tags and items. That said, I still wish there were a MODE aggregate function in MySQL.

Comment: There's no need to abbreviate `stuff` to `s` in the question.  In this case it makes it harder to spot that `category` belongs to the `s` rather than `t` table as they are both single characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT tag, category, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff USING (id)
      GROUP BY tag, category) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT tag, category, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff USING (id)
      GROUP BY tag, category) t2
  ON (t1.tag = t2.tag AND (t1.count < t2.count 
      OR t1.count = t2.count AND t1.category < t2.category))
WHERE t2.tag IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.count DESC;
```

---

I agree this is kind of too much for a single SQL query.  Any use of `GROUP BY` inside a subquery makes me wince.  You can make it *look* simpler by using views:

```
CREATE VIEW count_per_category AS
    SELECT tag, category, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff USING (id)
    GROUP BY tag, category;

SELECT t1.*
FROM count_per_category t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN count_per_category t2
  ON (t1.tag = t2.tag AND (t1.count < t2.count 
      OR t1.count = t2.count AND t1.category < t2.category))
WHERE t2.tag IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.count DESC;
```

But it's basically doing the same work behind the scenes.

You comment that you could do a similar operation easily in application code.  So why don't you do that?  Do the simpler query to get the counts per category:

```
SELECT tag, category, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff USING (id)
GROUP BY tag, category;
```

And sort through the result in application code.

Comment: I've been having difficulty getting that to work.. It would seem to be better to make an aggregate function MOST_FREQUENT().. I'm going to see if that is within my skill level here...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your schema.  I've taken a closer look and mocked up a test database so I could be sure the query works.  Try the edited version above.

Comment: That seems to work. It's a little tough to swallow though.. and there are two sub-selects instead of just one. I wish there were just a built in aggregate function MEAN() or something :-P. I could probably write that using C in like 5min.

Comment: See my additional content after the separator line.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  tag, category
FROM    (
        SELECT  @tag <> tag AS _new,
                @tag := tag AS tag,
                category, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @tag := ''
                ) vars,
                stuff
        GROUP BY
                tag, category
        ORDER BY
                tag, cnt DESC
        ) q
WHERE   _new
```

On your data, this returns the following:

```
'automotive',  8
'ba',          8
'bamboo',      8
'bananatree',  8
'bath',        9
```

Here's the test script:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, category INT NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    stuff
VALUES
('automotive',8),
('ba',8),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',10),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',9),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',10),
('bamboo',8),
('bamboo',9),
('bamboo',8),
('bananatree',8),
('bananatree',8),
('bananatree',8),
('bananatree',8),
('bath',9);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It avoids self joining a group by query, and should be a lot more efficient. it does a single group by and iterates it, marking the rows we need, and then filters them out. Smart!

Answer (score 3):

(Edit: forgot DESC in ORDER BYs)

Easy to do with a LIMIT in the subquery.  Does MySQL still have the no-LIMIT-in-subqueries restriction?  Below example is using PostgreSQL.

```
=> select tag, (select category from stuff z where z.tag = s.tag group by tag, category order by count(*) DESC limit 1) AS category, (select count(*) from stuff z where z.tag = s.tag group by tag, category order by count(*) DESC limit 1) AS num_items from stuff s group by tag;
    tag     | category | num_items 
------------+----------+-----------
 ba         |        8 |         1
 automotive |        8 |         1
 bananatree |        8 |         4
 bath       |        9 |         1
 bamboo     |        8 |         9
(5 rows)
```

Third column is only necessary if you need the count.

Answer (score 1):

This is for simpler situations:

`SELECT action, COUNT(action) AS ActionCount
FROM log
GROUP BY action
ORDER BY ActionCount DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky approach to this which utilizes the `max` aggregate function seeing as there is no mode aggregate function in MySQL (or windowing functions etc.) that would allow this:

```
SELECT  
  tag, 
  convert(substring(max(concat(lpad(c, 20, '0'), category)), 21), int) 
        AS most_frequent_category 
FROM (
    SELECT tag, category, count(*) AS c
    FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff using (id) 
    GROUP BY tag, category
) as grouped_cats 
GROUP BY tag;
```

Basically it utilizes the fact that we can find the lexical max of the counts of each individual category.

This is easier to see with named categories:

```
create temporary table tags (id int auto_increment primary key, tag character varying(20));
create temporary table stuff (id int, category character varying(20));
insert into tags (tag) values ('automotive'), ('ba'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('bamboo'), ('banana tree'), ('banana tree'), ('banana tree'), ('banana tree'), ('bath');
insert into stuff (id, category) values (1, 'cat-8'), (2, 'cat-8'), (3, 'cat-8'), (4, 'cat-8'), (5, 'cat-8'), (6, 'cat-8'), (7, 'cat-8'), (8, 'cat-10'), (9, 'cat-8'), (10, 'cat-9'), (11, 'cat-8'), (12, 'cat-10'), (13, 'cat-8'), (14, 'cat-9'), (15, 'cat-8'), (16, 'cat-8'), (17, 'cat-8'), (18, 'cat-8'), (19, 'cat-8'), (20, 'cat-9');
```

In which case we shouldn't be doing integer conversion on the `most_frequent_category` column:

```
SELECT 
  tag, 
  substring(max(concat(lpad(c, 20, '0'), category)), 21) AS most_frequent_category 
FROM (
    SELECT tag, category, count(*) AS c
    FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff using (id) 
    GROUP BY tag, category
) as grouped_cats 
GROUP BY tag;

+-------------+------------------------+
| tag         | most_frequent_category |
+-------------+------------------------+
| automotive  | cat-8                  |
| ba          | cat-8                  |
| bamboo      | cat-8                  |
| banana tree | cat-8                  |
| bath        | cat-9                  |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

And to delve a little bit more into what is going on, here's what the `grouped_cats` inner select looks like (I've added `order by tag, c desc`):

```
+-------------+----------+---+
| tag         | category | c |
+-------------+----------+---+
| automotive  | cat-8    | 1 |
| ba          | cat-8    | 1 |
| bamboo      | cat-8    | 9 |
| bamboo      | cat-10   | 2 |
| bamboo      | cat-9    | 2 |
| banana tree | cat-8    | 4 |
| bath        | cat-9    | 1 |
+-------------+----------+---+
```

And we can see how the max of the `count(*)` column drags along it's associated category if we omit the `substring` bit:

```
SELECT 
  tag, 
  max(concat(lpad(c, 20, '0'), category)) AS xmost_frequent_category
FROM (
    SELECT tag, category, count(*) AS c
    FROM tags INNER JOIN stuff using (id) 
    GROUP BY tag, category
) as grouped_cats 
GROUP BY tag;

+-------------+---------------------------+
| tag         | xmost_frequent_category   |
+-------------+---------------------------+
| automotive  | 00000000000000000001cat-8 |
| ba          | 00000000000000000001cat-8 |
| bamboo      | 00000000000000000009cat-8 |
| banana tree | 00000000000000000004cat-8 |
| bath        | 00000000000000000001cat-9 |
+-------------+---------------------------+
```