# Find most frequent value in SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find the most frequent value in a given column in an SQL table?

For example, for this table it should return `two` since it is the most frequent value:

```
one
two
two
three
```

Comment: GROUP BY version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344665/get-most-common-value-in-sql

Comment: What about ties? Add another 'three' row to the sample data, and specify the expected result.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  <column_name>,
  COUNT(<column_name>) AS `value_occurrence` 

FROM
  <my_table>

GROUP BY 
  <column_name>

ORDER BY 
  `value_occurrence` DESC

LIMIT 1;
```

Replace `<column_name>` and `<my_table>`. Increase `1` if you want to see the `N` most common values of the column.

Comment: what what should I do if I want to select another fields too from  'my_table'? In the other words, another value;

Comment: what if more than one value appear same no of times (which is max)? In this case, if three also appeared twice? LIMIT 1 will show only one record

Comment: @mustafa1993 `SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY value ORDER BY  count(*) DESC;`

Comment: why doesn't it work when i add `WHERE 'value_occurrence' = 1` ?

Comment: @swisswiss you must use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` in this case.

Comment: Do all the accents (`) have any purpose in this query?

Comment: @mustafa1993 I've covered the case where you want to get all that match the moast frequent at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72979899/895245

Answer (score 66):

Try something like:

```
SELECT       `column`
    FROM     `your_table`
    GROUP BY `column`
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT    1;
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could use `COUNT(*)` directly in the `ORDER BY`. I knew there were a few restrictions regarding `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` and aggregate columns and I always assumed that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 32):

Let us consider table name as `tblperson` and column name as `city`. I want to retrieve the most repeated city from the city column:

```
 select city,count(*) as nor from tblperson
        group by city
          having count(*) =(select max(nor) from 
            (select city,count(*) as nor from tblperson group by city) tblperson)
```

Here `nor` is an alias name.

Comment: +1 for using standard SQL that will work in any database (whereas LIMIT is MySQL specific, TOP is SQL Server specific).

Answer (score 17):

Below query seems to work good for me in SQL Server database:

```
select column, COUNT(column) AS MOST_FREQUENT
from TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY column
ORDER BY COUNT(column) DESC
```

Result:

```
column          MOST_FREQUENT
item1           highest count
item2           second highest 
item3           third higest
..
..
```

Answer (score 3):

For use with SQL Server.

As there is no limit command support in that.

Yo can use the top 1 command to find the maximum occurring value in the particular column in this case (value)

```
SELECT top1 
    `value`,
    COUNT(`value`) AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM     
    `my_table`
GROUP BY 
    `value`
ORDER BY 
    `value_occurrence` DESC;
```

Comment: You also need to move COUNT function to ORDER BY section to avoid getting the following error: 
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Table is '`SalesLT.Customer`' and the Column you are trying to figure out is '`CompanyName`' and `AggCompanyName` is an Alias.

```
Select CompanyName, Count(CompanyName) as AggCompanyName from SalesLT.Customer
group by CompanyName
Order By Count(CompanyName) Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use LIMIT or LIMIT is not an option for your query tool. You can use "ROWNUM" instead, but you will need a sub query:

```
SELECT FIELD_1, ALIAS1
FROM(SELECT FIELD_1, COUNT(FIELD_1) ALIAS1
    FROM TABLENAME
    GROUP BY FIELD_1
    ORDER BY COUNT(FIELD_1) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `ROWNUM`

Comment: This is valid for oracle but not mysql

Comment: @Prabhu in MySQL, you use `LIMIT 1` instead; syntax is shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID column and you want to find most repetitive category from another column for each ID then you can use below query,

**Table:**

[image: Table content]

Query:

```sql
SELECT ID, CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS FREQ
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 1,2
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FREQ DESC) = 1;
```

**Result:**

[image: Query result]

Answer (score 0):

**Return all most frequent rows in case of tie**

[Find the most frequent value in mysql,display all in case of a tie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986026/find-the-most-frequent-value-in-mysql-display-all-in-case-of-a-tie/63986233#63986233) gives two possible approaches:

1. Scalar subquery:

   ```
   SELECT
     "country",
     COUNT(country) AS "cnt"
   FROM "Sales"
   GROUP BY "country"
   HAVING
     COUNT("country") = (
       SELECT COUNT("country") AS "cnt"
       FROM "Sales"
       GROUP BY "country"
       ORDER BY "cnt" DESC,
       LIMIT 1
     )
   ORDER BY "country" ASC
   ```
2. With the `RANK` window function, available since MySQL 8+:

   ```
   SELECT "country", "cnt"
     FROM (
       SELECT
         "country",
         COUNT("country") AS "cnt",
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) "rnk"
       FROM "Sales"
       GROUP BY "country"
     ) AS "sub"
   WHERE "rnk" = 1
   ORDER BY "country" ASC
   ```

   This method might save a second recount compared to the first one.

   `RANK` works by ranking all rows, such that if two rows are at the top, both get rank `1`. So it basically directly solves this type of use case.

   `RANK` is also available on SQLite and PostgreSQL, I think it might be SQL standard, not sure.

In the above queries I also sorted by `country` to have more deterministic results.

Tested on SQLite 3.34.0, PostgreSQL 14.3, [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/0b3be5107e7fd37f75f7863b95d97804cef4d4d1/nodejs/sequelize/raw/most_frequent.js).

**Most frequent for each `GROUP BY` group**

- MySQL: [MySQL SELECT most frequent by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407723/mysql-select-most-frequent-by-group)
- PostgreSQL:

  - [Get most common value for each value of another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344665/get-most-common-value-for-each-value-of-another-column-in-sql)
  - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193307/find-most-frequent-values-for-a-given-column
- SQLite: [SQL query for finding the most frequent value of a grouped by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432789/sql-query-for-finding-the-most-frequent-value-of-a-grouped-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     TOP 20 WITH TIES COUNT(Counted_Column) AS Count, OtherColumn1, 
OtherColumn2, OtherColumn3, OtherColumn4
FROM         Table_or_View_Name
WHERE
(Date_Column >= '01/01/2023') AND 
(Date_Column <= '03/01/2023') AND 
(Counted_Column = 'Desired_Text')
GROUP BY OtherColumn1, OtherColumn2, OtherColumn3, OtherColumn4
ORDER BY COUNT(Counted_Column) DESC
```

- 20 can be changed to any desired number
- WITH TIES allows all ties in the count to be displayed
- Date range used if date/time column exists and can be modified to search a date range as desired
- Counted_Column 'Desired_Text' can be modified to only count certain entries in that column
- Works in INSQL for my instance

Answer (score -1):

One way I like to use is:

```
select *<given_column>*,COUNT(*<given_column>*)as VAR1 from Table_Name

group by *<given_column>*

order by VAR1 desc

limit 1
```