# Find values repeated exactly N times in column

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I find the values in an SQL column that are repeated exactly N times? For example, let's say I have a column that has the values `fanta, sprite, sprite, sprite, cola, cola, cola, cabbages, cabbages, cabbages, cabbages`, and I want to find the values which is repeated exactly 3 times, which should return `sprite` and `cola`, but not `fanta` or `cabbages`, because they are not repeated exactly 3 times.

I tried to adapt the SQL from [Find most frequent value in SQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235595/find-most-frequent-value-in-sql-column):

```
SELECT value1, COUNT(value1) AS value1_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY value1
WHERE value1_count=3
```

But that gives me `near "WHERE": syntax error:`, so obviously I'm not doing it right.

**Edit:** [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) was suggested as exact duplicate, but it is about finding all repeated values, regardless of how many times they are repeated, though I admit the answers there make it obvious how to reach a solution in my case, so I don't know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Group by` + [`Having` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx):

```
SELECT value1, COUNT(value1) AS value1_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY value1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52ef9/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

To apply a condition on `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING`.

Try this:

```
SELECT value1, COUNT(value1) AS value1_count FROM table1
GROUP BY value1
HAVING COUNT(value1) = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use HAVING clause with aggregate functions .. Below is the example

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/563de/2)**