# Maximum occurance of number(id) in a table - Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table with details regarding a user subscription(id, user_id, plan_id, product_id, amount..etc).
I wanted to get favourite plan and product by getting maximum occurance of an id `(plan_id, product_id)` in a table column.

I was trying to use this
[Find most frequent value in SQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235595/find-most-frequent-value-in-sql-column). But didn't work out.

Here is my query for favorite plan:

```
$subs = Subscription::findBySql("SELECT  plan_id, COUNT(plan_id) AS `value_occurrence` FROM subscription GROUP BY plan_id
            ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I just need the maximum occurance of `plan_id` and `product_id`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *But didn't work out* - can you explain it more clearly ? you get an error or wrong result ? what is `var_dump($subs)` output ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need count of the occurrence of the plan_id and product_id in this way (I suppose your model is called Subscription):

```
$plantCounts = Subcription::find()
  ->select(['COUNT(*) AS value_occurrence'])
  ->orderBy(['value_occurrence'= DESC ]
  ->groupBy(['plan_id'])
  ->one();
```

Answer (score -1):

From any row whatsoever even on different rows as a source, you want the max of plan_id and the max of product_id ?   1 row total coming back?

```
select max(plan_id) as plmax,
max(product_id) as prodmax
from subscription
```

Comment: Just column names so u can use them like column names in your resultset of 1 row

Comment: Otherwise as aggregate functions it is harder to refer to them