# How to modify query to walk entire table rather than a single

Tags: sql, db2

I wrote several SQL queries and executed them against my table. Each individual query worked. I kept adding functionality until I got a really ugly working query. The problem is that I have to manually change a value every time I want to use it. Can you assist in making this query automatic rather than “manual”?

I am working with DB2.

Table below shows customers (cid) from 1 to 3. 'club' is a book seller, and 'qnty' is the number of books the customer bought from each 'club'. The full table has 45 customers.
[image]

Image below shows all the table elements for the first 3 users (cid=1 OR cid=2 OR cid=3). The final purpose of all my queries (once combined) is it to find the single 'club' with the largest 'qnty' for each 'cid'. So for 'cid =1' the 'club' is Readers Digest with 'qnty' of 3. For 'cid=2' the 'club' is YRB Gold with 'qnty' of 5. On and on until cid 45 is reached.

[image]

To give you a background on what I did here are my queries:

(Query 1-starting point for `cid=1`)

`SELECT * FROM yrb_purchase WHERE cid=1`
[image]

(Query 2 - find the 'club' with the highest 'qnty' for cid=1)

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT club,
        sum(qnty) AS t_qnty
FROM yrb_purchase
WHERE cid=1
GROUP BY club)results
ORDER BY t_qnty DESC
```

[image]

(Query 3 – combine the record from the above query with it’s cid)

```
SELECT cid,
    temp.club,
    temp.t_qnty
FROM yrb_purchase AS p,

(SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT club,
            sum(qnty) AS t_qnty
    FROM yrb_purchase
    WHERE cid=1
    GROUP BY club)results
ORDER BY t_qnty DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) AS TEMP
WHERE p.cid=1
AND p.club=temp.club
```

[image]

(Query 4) make sure there is only one record for cid=1

```
SELECT cid,
    temp.club,
    temp.t_qnty
FROM yrb_purchase AS p,

(SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT club,
            sum(qnty) AS t_qnty
    FROM yrb_purchase
    WHERE cid=1
    GROUP BY club)results
ORDER BY t_qnty DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) AS TEMP
WHERE p.cid=1
AND p.club=temp.club FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
```

[image]

To get the 'club' with the highest 'qnty' for customer 2, I would simply change the text cid=1 to cid=2 in the last query above. My query seems to always produce the correct results. My question is, how do I modify my query to get the results for all 'cid's from 1 to 45 in a single table? How do I get a table with all the cid values along with the club which sold that cid the most books, and how many books were sold within one tablei? Please keep in mind I am hoping you can modify my query as opposed to you providing a better query.

If you decide that my query is way too ugly (I agree with you) and choose to provide another query, please be aware that I just started learning SQL and may not be able to understand your query. You should be aware that I already asked this question: [For common elements, how to find the value based on two columns? SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609289/for-common-elements-how-to-find-the-value-based-on-two-columns-sql) but I was not able to make the answer work (due to my SQL limitations - not because the answer wasn't good); and in the absence of a working answer I could not reverse engineer it to understand how it works.
Thanks in advance

****************************EDIT #1*******************************************
The results of the answer is:

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OLAP/Window Functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    cid,
    club,
    qnty
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            cid,
            club,
            qnty,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cid order by qnty desc) as cid_club_rank
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    cid,
                    club, 
                    sum(qnty) as qnty   
                FROM yrb_purchase 
                GROUP BY cid, club
            ) as sub1
    ) as sub2
WHERE cid_club_rank = 1
```

The inner most statement (sub1) just grabs a total quantity for each cid/club combination. The second inner most statement (sub2) creates a row_number for each cid/club combination ordering by the quantity (top down). Then the outer most query chooses only records where that row_number() is 1.

Comment: Thanks for helping! When I run your query I am getting an error. The message is: `SQL0104N  An unexpected token "yrb_purchase" was found following "(qnty) as qnty, FROM".  Expected tokens may include:  "FROM".  SQLSTATE=42601` Any advice?

Comment: Sorry there was a stray comma in there.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you... I am trying to make the answer work, but I keep hitting walls I don't understand. Now it's the error `SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "SUB" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884`. I tried to find the `sub()` function online to understand it, but oddly, I am not having much luck. Again, really appreciate your time!

Comment: Sorry. Lots of fat fingering happening. That is supposed to be `sum()`. I have updated the query. No worries on the questions!

Comment: Thank you for getting me to this point! I put an image of the query results in the body of the posting as "edit #1". What modification needs to happen to the query to give me only one 'club' and 'qnty' per 'cid' (the 'club' with the largest 'qnty')?

Comment: I just made another edit to partition only on CID for the ROW_NUMBER() olap function. I think that should do the trick.