# Find the most frequent value in mysql,display all in case of a tie

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

For example, we have `1`, `2` and `3` are the most frequent values at the same time, how to return them when it is a tie?

```
id
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself before posting here?

Comment: I have have tried max(count()), but it seems like having a syntax error here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable
                   GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

On more recent versions of MySQL 8+, we can use `RANK` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT id
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```