# Select the most frequent metric value

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I need to create a *PromQL* query to select the most frequent metric value and display it in a Grafana panel; something like ([Find most frequent value in SQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12235595/14066835))

In the following example, for metric `status` with label `job`,

I want to display in a panel *status* **1** (given count for **`1` = *2***, count for `2` = *1*, count for `3` = *1*) (and possibly use that `1` in Grafana, i.e., as a value in the *Values Mapping* section of a panel such as [Polystat](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-polystat-panel)).

```
status(job="a") = 1
status(job="b") = 2
status(job="c") = 1
status(job="d") = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
count_values("val", status)
```

You can try to apply `topk(1, ...)` on that, but it is tricky (what if two top values have the same number of occurrences?).

Comment: I've being playing around with this and it looks promising! It'll show `{job="1"} 2` and I could simply display `1` using `{{job}}` as a _Legend_. What if something more "sophisticated" is needed such as using that **`1`** as a value in the _Values Mapping_ section?

Answer (score 1):

The query `max(count_values("value",status)) == ignoring(value) group_right count_values("value",status)` will give you
`{value="1"} 2` (and unlike `topk` may give you more rows if several metrics have the same maximal count).

Then in Grafana you just need to display the label from the result.

Comment: Thank you! This is quite an interesting solution which has a similar result as the other one posted here: It'll show `{job="1"} 2` and I could simply display `1` using `{{job}}` as a _Legend_. What if something more "sophisticated" is needed such as using that **`1`** as a value in the _Values Mapping_ section?

Comment: @jbuddy This depends on what exactly you want to do (and, I think, if your Grafana is a current version), but most likely it will help you to set "Format" to "Table" in Grafana query editor (and probably turn on the "Instant" switch).

Comment: Yeah, this is getting trickier, I'm trying to use that **`1`** as a value in the _Values Mapping_ section of  [Polystat](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-polystat-panel). Example value: **`1`** -> text : `Running`.