# get the most common value for each column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm attempting to create an **SQL** query that retrieves the `total_cost` for every row in a table. Alongside that, I also need to collect the most dominant value for both `columnA` and `columnB`, with their respective values.

For example, with the following table contents:

| cost | columnA | columnB | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | Foo | Bar | XYZ |
| 200 | Foo | Bar | XYZ |
| 150 | Bar | Bar | ABC |
| 250 | Foo | Bar | ABC |

The result would need to be:

| total_cost | columnA_dominant | columnB_dominant | columnA_value | columnB_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 850 | Foo | Bar | 250 | 400 |

Now I can get as far as calculating the total cost - that's no issue. I can also get the most dominant value for `columnA` using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235631/6425936). But after this, I'm not sure how to *also* get the dominant value for `columnB` *and* the values too.

This is my current SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`cost`) AS `total_cost`,
    COUNT(`columnA`) AS `columnA_dominant` 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `columnA_dominant`
ORDER BY `columnA_dominant` DESC
WHERE `target` = "ABC"
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to *@Barmar* for the idea of using a subquery, I managed to get the dominant values for `columnA` and `columnB`:

```
SELECT 
    -- Retrieve total cost.
    SUM(`cost`) AS `total_cost`,
    -- Get dominant values.
    (
        SELECT `columnA`
        FROM `table`
        GROUP BY `columnA`
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `columnA_dominant`,
    (
        SELECT `columnB`
        FROM `table`
        GROUP BY `columnB`
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS `columnB_dominant`
FROM `table`
WHERE `target` = "XYZ"
```

However, I'm still having issues figuring out how to calculate the respective values.

Comment: You need a subquery for each column to get the most common value of that column. Join all these subqueries to get all of them in a single row.

Comment: @Barmar See update.

Comment: Put the queries that get the most dominant value in a subquery. Then you can do `SUM(columnA = columnA_dominant) / COUNT(*) AS columnA_percentage`

Answer (score 3):

You might get close, if we want to get percentage values we can try to add `COUNT(*)` at subquery to get max count by `columnA` and `columnB` then do division by total `count`

```
SELECT 
    SUM(cost),
    (
        SELECT tt.columnA
        FROM T tt
        GROUP BY tt.columnA
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )  AS columnA_dominant,
    (
        SELECT tt.columnB
        FROM T tt
        GROUP BY tt.columnB
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )  AS columnB_dominant,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM T tt
        GROUP BY tt.columnA
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) / COUNT(*) AS columnA_percentage,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM T tt
        GROUP BY tt.columnB
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) / COUNT(*) AS columnB_percentage
FROM T t1
```

If your MySQL version supports the window function, there is another way which reduce table scan might get better performance than a correlated subquery

```
SELECT SUM(cost) OVER(),
       FIRST_VALUE(columnA) OVER (ORDER BY counter1 DESC) columnA_dominant,
       FIRST_VALUE(columnB) OVER (ORDER BY counter2 DESC) columnB_dominant,
       FIRST_VALUE(counter1) OVER (ORDER BY counter1 DESC) / COUNT(*) OVER() columnA_percentage,
       FIRST_VALUE(counter2) OVER (ORDER BY counter2 DESC) / COUNT(*) OVER() columnB_percentage
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA) counter1,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnB) counter2  
  FROM T
) t1
LIMIT 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70da59b74c3af4d7414f885e4630ef5d)

Comment: @GROVER. We can just add `SUM` instead of `COUNT` from the query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fec41c4bd40439fac7532fbdd5c8c49b

Comment: If I add a where condition to the main query, for some reason the subqueries return the incorrect results? Ie. `WHERE `columnC` = "XYZ"`. Do I need to add the same where condition to ALL the subqueries?

Comment: Yes, You need to add conditions for that or compare `columnC` which might equal the subquery table and main table.

Comment: See updated question. Might make more sense lol :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
select sum(cost) as total_cost,p.columnA,q.columnB,p.columnA_percentage,q.columnB_percentage
from get_common,(
select top 1 columnA,columnA_percentage
from(
select columnA,count(columnA) as count_columnA,cast(count(columnA) as float)/(select count(columnA) from get_common) as columnA_percentage
from get_common
group by columnA)s
order by count_columnA desc
)p,
(select top 1 columnB,columnB_percentage
from (
select columnB,count(columnB) as count_columnB, cast(count(columnB) as float)/(select count(columnB) from get_common) as columnB_percentage
from get_common
group by columnB) t
order by count_columnB desc)q
group by p.columnA,q.columnB,p.columnA_percentage,q.columnB_percentage
```

so if you want to get the percent and dominant value you must make their own query like this

```
select top 1 columnA,columnA_percentage
from(
select columnA,count(columnA) as count_columnA,cast(count(columnA) as float)/(select count(columnA) from get_common) as columnA_percentage
from get_common
group by columnA)s
order by count_columnA desc
```

then you can join with the sum query to get all value you want

hope this can help you

Comment: Sorry, I realised the way I was going about things was incorrect. I was meant to get their respective `values` not their percentages. See updated question.