# SQL: Returning the most common value for each person

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

EDIT: I'm using MySQL, I found another post with the same question, but it's in Postgres; I require MySQL.

[Get most common value for each value of another column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344665/get-most-common-value-in-sql)

I ask this question after extensive searching of this site and others but have not found a result that works as I intend it to.

I have a table of people (recordid, personid, transactionid) and a transaction table (transactionid, rating). I require a single SQL statement that can return the most common rating each person has.

I currently have this SQL statement that returns the most common rating for a specified person id. It works and perhaps it may help others.

```
SELECT transactionTable.rating as MostCommonRating 
FROM personTable, transactionTable 
WHERE personTable.transactionid = transactionTable.transactionid 
AND personTable.personid = 1
GROUP BY transactionTable.rating 
ORDER BY COUNT(transactionTable.rating) desc 
LIMIT 1
```

However I require a statement that does what the above statement does for each personid in personTable.

My attempt is below; however, it times out my MySQL server.

```
SELECT personid AS pid, 
(SELECT transactionTable.rating as MostCommonRating 
FROM personTable, transactionTable 
WHERE personTable.transactionid = transactionTable.transactionid 
AND personTable.personid = pid
GROUP BY transactionTable.rating 
ORDER BY COUNT(transactionTable.rating) desc 
LIMIT 1)
FROM persontable
GROUP BY personid
```

Any help you can give me would be much obliged. Thanks.

**`PERSONTABLE`**:

```
RecordID,   PersonID,   TransactionID
1,      Adam,       1
2,      Adam,       2
3,      Adam,       3
4,      Ben,        1
5,      Ben,        3
6,      Ben,        4
7,      Caitlin,    4
8,      Caitlin,    5
9,      Caitlin,    1
```

**`TRANSACTIONTABLE`**:

```
TransactionID,  Rating
1       Good
2       Bad
3       Good
4       Average
5       Average
```

The output of the SQL statement I am searching for would be:

**OUTPUT**:

```
PersonID,   MostCommonRating
Adam        Good
Ben         Good
Caitlin     Average
```

Comment: Please tag with the database engine you're using.

Comment: I'm about to head out for a few hours so can only check this again in like 5 hours,but, a few things pop to mind.  Have you tried putting an index on any of these columns? That is likely the reason your SQL server is timing out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx

Comment: I think you have a typo in the first row in the `TRANSACTIONTABLE` `1 GOOD` shouldn't be `1 Very bad` because you have `3   GOOD`??

Comment: The typo is not the cause, these examples are simply to simulate the problem I am having, they are not the actual data I am working with.

Comment: This post is the same as mine but the answer is in POSTGRES I require MYSQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344665/get-most-common-value-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT most frequent by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407723/mysql-select-most-frequent-by-group)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Preliminary comment

Please learn to use the explicit JOIN notation, not the old (pre-1992) implicit join notation.

Old style:

```
SELECT transactionTable.rating as MostCommonRating 
FROM personTable, transactionTable 
WHERE personTable.transactionid = transactionTable.transactionid 
AND personTable.personid = 1
GROUP BY transactionTable.rating 
ORDER BY COUNT(transactionTable.rating) desc 
LIMIT 1
```

Preferred style:

```
SELECT transactionTable.rating AS MostCommonRating 
  FROM personTable
  JOIN transactionTable 
    ON personTable.transactionid = transactionTable.transactionid 
 WHERE personTable.personid = 1
 GROUP BY transactionTable.rating 
 ORDER BY COUNT(transactionTable.rating) desc 
 LIMIT 1
```

You need an ON condition for each JOIN.

Also, the `personID` values in the data are strings, not numbers, so you'd need to write

```
 WHERE personTable.personid = "Ben"
```

for example, to get the query to work on the tables shown.

---

### Main answer

You're seeking to find an aggregate of an aggregate: in this case, the maximum of a count.  So, any general solution is going to involve both MAX and COUNT.  You can't apply MAX directly to COUNT, but you can apply MAX to a column from a sub-query where the column happens to be a COUNT.

Build the query up using Test-Driven Query Design — TDQD.

#### Select person and transaction rating

```
SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, t.TransactionID
  FROM PersonTable AS p
  JOIN TransactionTable AS t
    ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
```

#### Select person, rating, and number of occurrences of rating

```
SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
  FROM PersonTable AS p
  JOIN TransactionTable AS t
    ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
 GROUP BY p.PersonID, t.Rating
```

This result will become a sub-query.

#### Find the maximum number of times the person gets any rating

```
SELECT s.PersonID, MAX(s.RatingCount)
  FROM (SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
          FROM PersonTable AS p
          JOIN TransactionTable AS t
            ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
         GROUP BY p.PersonID, t.Rating
       ) AS s
 GROUP BY s.PersonID
```

Now we know which is the maximum count for each person.

### Required result

To get the result, we need to select the rows from the sub-query which have the maximum count.  Note that if someone has 2 Good and 2 Bad ratings (and 2 is the maximum number of ratings of the same type for that person), then two records will be shown for that person.

```
SELECT s.PersonID, s.Rating
  FROM (SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
          FROM PersonTable AS p
          JOIN TransactionTable AS t
            ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
         GROUP BY p.PersonID, t.Rating
       ) AS s
  JOIN (SELECT s.PersonID, MAX(s.RatingCount) AS MaxRatingCount
          FROM (SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
                  FROM PersonTable AS p
                  JOIN TransactionTable AS t
                    ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
                 GROUP BY p.PersonID, t.Rating
               ) AS s
         GROUP BY s.PersonID
       ) AS m
    ON s.PersonID = m.PersonID AND s.RatingCount = m.MaxRatingCount
```

If you want the actual rating count too, that's easily selected.

That's a fairly complex piece of SQL.  I would hate to try writing that from scratch.  Indeed, I probably wouldn't bother; I'd develop it step-by-step, more or less as shown.  But because we've debugged the sub-queries before we use them in bigger expressions, we can be confident of the answer.

#### WITH clause

Note that Standard SQL provides a WITH clause that prefixes a SELECT statement, naming a sub-query.  (It can also be used for recursive queries, but we aren't needing that here.)

```
WITH RatingList AS
     (SELECT p.PersonID, t.Rating, COUNT(*) AS RatingCount
        FROM PersonTable AS p
        JOIN TransactionTable AS t
          ON p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
       GROUP BY p.PersonID, t.Rating
     )
SELECT s.PersonID, s.Rating
  FROM RatingList AS s
  JOIN (SELECT s.PersonID, MAX(s.RatingCount) AS MaxRatingCount
          FROM RatingList AS s
         GROUP BY s.PersonID
       ) AS m
    ON s.PersonID = m.PersonID AND s.RatingCount = m.MaxRatingCount
```

This is simpler to write.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not yet support the WITH clause.

---

The SQL above has now been tested against IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.70.FC2 running on Mac OS X 10.7.4.  That test exposed the problem diagnosed in the preliminary comment.  The SQL for the main answer worked correctly without needing to be changed.

Comment: +1, Great Answer, I have been trying to do it for more than have an hour. Here is a [Live demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80151/returning-the-aggregate-of-an-aggregate-the-maximum-of-a-count). But is there any common name for such a problem? Is it the aggregate of an aggregate? or what. Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for this it help heaps. It was easy to understand because of the way you set it out and developed the query over time. A+

Comment: As a substitute for the WITH clause, you can use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RatingList AS _select-statement_.

Comment: Sigh, that doesn't work - MySQL doesn't let you refer to a temporary table multiple times in a query. You need to create a real table.

Comment: @Barmar: Bad luck.  Those sorts of restrictions — non-obvious and not obviously necessary — are irksome in a DBMS.  But not being able to use a temp table name multiple times in a single query does seem like a peculiar restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat hacky abuse of the fact that the `max` aggregate function in MySQL does lexical sorting on varchars (as well as the expected numerical sorting on integers/floats):

```
SELECT 
  PersonID, 
  substring(max(concat(lpad(c, 20, '0'), Rating)), 21) AS MostFrequentRating 
FROM (
    SELECT PersonID, Rating, count(*) c 
    FROM PERSONTABLE INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONTABLE USING(TransactionID) 
    GROUP BY PersonID, Rating
) AS grouped_ratings 
GROUP BY PersonID;
```

Which gives the desired:

```
+----------+--------------------+
| PersonID | MostFrequentRating |
+----------+--------------------+
| Adam     | Good               |
| Ben      | Good               |
| Caitlin  | Average            |
+----------+--------------------+
```

(note, if there are multiple modes per person, it will pick the one with the highest alphabetic entry, so — pretty much randomly — Good over Bad and Bad over Average)

You should be able to see what the `max` is operating over by examining the following:

```
SELECT PersonID, Rating, count(*) c, concat(lpad(count(*), 20, '0'), Rating) as LexicalMaxMe 
FROM PERSONTABLE INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONTABLE USING(TransactionID) 
GROUP BY PersonID, Rating
ORDER BY PersonID, c DESC;
```

Which outputs:

```
+----------+---------+---+-----------------------------+
| PersonID | Rating  | c | LexicalMaxMe                |
+----------+---------+---+-----------------------------+
| Adam     | Good    | 2 | 00000000000000000002Good    |
| Adam     | Bad     | 1 | 00000000000000000001Bad     |
| Ben      | Good    | 2 | 00000000000000000002Good    |
| Ben      | Average | 1 | 00000000000000000001Average |
| Caitlin  | Average | 2 | 00000000000000000002Average |
| Caitlin  | Good    | 1 | 00000000000000000001Good    |    
+----------+---------+---+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Microsoft SQL Server: You have the possibility to create a custom aggregate function to get the most common value. Example 2 of this blog post by Ahmed Tarek Hasan describes how to do it:

http://developmentsimplyput.blogspot.nl/2013/03/creating-sql-custom-user-defined.html