# Subselect and group by

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables :

main : id_main, field1, filter

main_logs (50 millions lines) : auto inc, id_main, path

I looking for the following results : 
id_main, field1, most common path

I tried the following query :

```
select id_main, 
  field1, 
  (select path, count(*) as cpt 
   from main_log 
   where main_log.id_main=main.id_main group by path order by cpt desc limit 1) 
from main 
where filter in (1,3,5);
```

Mysql return : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

If I remove path, results are correct, but I miss the path value.

```
select id_main, 
  field1, 
  (select path, count(*) as cpt 
   from main_log 
   where main_log.id_main=main.id_main group by path order by cpt desc limit 1) 
from main 
where filter in (1,3,5);
```

I don't need the result of count(*) but I need it for the "order by"

How can I write this query to get my results ?
Thanks

**main**

```
id_main     | field1    | filter
1       | red       | 1
2       | blue      | 3
3       | pink      | 1
```

**main_logs**

```
autoinc     | id_main   | path
1       | 1         | home1
2       | 1         | home2
3       | 1         | home2
4       | 2         | house2
5       | 2         | house7
6       | 2         | house7
7       | 3         | casee
```

**expected result**

```
id_main     | fields1   | most common path
1       | red       | home2
2       | blue      | house7
3       | pink      | casee
```

Comment: Can you show the results you need?

Comment: I need each line from "main" table, including the most common path for id_main from the "main_log" table

Comment: I think the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446368/sql-returning-the-most-common-value-for-each-person provides the way to structure your subquery. Then you can join it with the `main` table.

Comment: The query you are trying is a dependant query which will take more time then mine and @Saharsh Shah which is perfect

Comment: I only need 5% of main_logs, so I can't do the group by wihout condition

Comment: @benfromaix in `main` table there's no `filter` data anymore

Comment: @benfromaix +1 for the interesting question

Comment: I added filter in my sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use :

```
SELECT id_main, field, 
    (SELECT path 
    FROM main_logs 
    WHERE id_main=main.id_main 
    GROUP BY path 
    ORDER BY count(path) DESC 
    LIMIT 1) AS most 
FROM main 
WHERE filter IN (1,3,5);
```

Tested, it's working.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id_main, m.field1, A.path 
FROM main m 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT id_main, path, COUNT(*) cnt
                  FROM main_log ml  
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM main m WHERE ml.id_main = m.id_main AND filter IN (1,3,5))
                  GROUP BY id_main, path 
                  ORDER BY cnt DESC
                  ) AS A 
            GROUP BY id_main
            ) AS A ON m.id_main = A.id_main;
```

**OLD CODE IGNORE**

```
SELECT m.id_main, m.field1, A.path 
FROM main m 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id_main, path, count(*) cnt
            FROM main_log 
            GROUP BY id_main, path 
            ORDER BY cnt DESC) GROUP BY id_main) as A on m.id_main = A.id_main 
WHERE filter IN (1,3,5);
```

Comment: I think it could works on small dataset, but in my case mysql gone crazy (ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_11dc_1.MYI'; try to repair it) because the main_log table is huge (5Go). This query need to execute the subselect group by on all the table, without any condition. I can't do that

Comment: Do you have an index on `id_main` in both tables?

Comment: It's the primary key in "main" table and it's an index in "main_log"

Comment: Add index on path column and try to run query

Comment: actually there is one on path too. But a group by path without any where condition requiere a huge temp table size. This is why I tried to get the most common path for each id_main instead of a huge query

Comment: Check my updated answer and provide me the output of EXPLAIN query

Comment: I tried with an explain but mysql can't provide an answer with the smale error answer. The subset from main_log can't be queried without condition, the table contain 40 millions lines, and I only need 5% of line with my option

Comment: Check my updated query and update me if it works or not. I will remove old query if my new query works

Answer (score 0):

You are returning two columns int he sub query. You just need to return one.

Sample data:

```
ID_MAIN     FIELD1  FILTER
1   h   1
2   x   2
3   y   3


AUTOINC     ID_MAIN     PATH
11  1   abc
12  2   abd
13  1   xyz
14  1   ghf
15  2   xyz
```

Try tis out: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a491/4)

Query:

```
select id_main, 
  field1, 
  (select count(id_main) as cpt 
   from main_logs 
   where main_logs.id_main=main.id_main 
   group by path 
   order by cpt desc limit 1) as CPTs
from main 
where filter in (1,3,5);
```

Results:

```
ID_MAIN     FIELD1  CPTs
1       h   1
3       y   (null)
```

### Edit to provide max count per path for each ID

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d12b1/1)

Definitely not the most elegant query. Too may joins and subqueries could result in rather ridiculous performance laggging.

Follow your Sample data, except that table `main`, id = 3, pink filter = 5. So it complies with your `filter` criteria. However even without that critieria, the following query seems to work well for the logic.

Query:

```
select a.id, b.path, a.mx
from
(select x.id, x.path, max(x.ct) as mx
from (
select m.id_main as id, ml.path, 
count(ml.id_main) as ct
from main m
left join 
main_logs ml
on ml.id_main = m.id_main
group by ml.path) as x
group by x.id) as a
inner join 
(select m.id_main as id, m.filter, ml.path, 
count(ml.id_main) as ct
from main m
left join 
main_logs ml
on ml.id_main = m.id_main
group by ml.path) as b
on a.id = b.id
and a.mx = b.ct
where b.filter in (1,2,3)
order by a.mx desc
;
```

Results:

```
ID  PATH    MX
1   home2   2
2   house7  2
3   casee   1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need the most common path in my sql result, not the number of occurence

Comment: @benfromaix sample data and your expected output wuold have been helpful ;)

Comment: @benfromaix I have updated the answer with a query that is *very ugly on performance*. Please give it a try :)

Comment: unfortunaly Mysql still can't play this query because it's too huge.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    m.id_main,
    m.field1,
    ml.path,
    IFNULL(ml.Count,0)
FROM main as m
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT
                 id_main, 
                 path,
                 COUNT(path) as Count
           FROM main_logs
           GROUP BY id_main
          ) as ml on ml.id_main = m.id_main
```

Comment: same answer here : 
 
I think it could works on small dataset, but in my case mysql gone crazy (ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_11dc_1.MYI'; try to repair it) because the main_log table is huge (5Go). This query need to execute the subselect group by on all the table, without any condition. I can't do that