# Adding null values for records not existing in joined table

Tags: mysql

I have a table, called `top_trends` which has the following schema:

```
id int(11) AI PK 
criteria_id int(11) 
value varchar(255) 
created_at timestamp 
updated_at timestamp
```

Then I have another table, called `search_criterias` which has the following schema:

```
id int(11) AI PK 
title varchar(255) 
created_at timestamp 
updated_at timestamp
```

Here is a query which provides the value based on maximum number of records by a value. So, if theres 2 records in `top_trends` with both having `criteria_id` as 1 and both have values of 3 in the `top_trends.value` column, and then a separate SINGLE record with the same criteria_id 1 but a value of 2, the query will produce a result of the selected criteria (being 1) having a value of 3 since the value 3 occurred more times than any other rows of values with criteria_id 1. So, in simple terms, the query chose the value 3 for criteria id 1 because that occurred the most amount of times based on the records in the top_trends having `criteria_id` 1

```
select
  x.value as `values`
  , sc.id as id
  , sc.title
  , sc.created_at
  , sc.updated_at
  , x.criteria_id as search_category_id 
from
  ( 
    select
      criteria_id
      , `value` 
    from
      top_trends 
    group by
      `criteria_id` 
    order by
      `value`
  ) x 
  left join search_criterias sc 
    on sc.id = x.criteria_id 
group by
  criteria_id
```

My issue is that unfortunately right now we dont have data for all possible `search_criterias` so some of the records in the `search_criteria` table are not being aggregated in my query.

For example, we have a search_criteria record of city, with an id of 5, but no records in the top_trends table with having a criteria_id of 5... so the query above is not including that search_criteria.

What I'd like to do is include those records in the `search_criteria` table that are not in the `top_trends` table but have the `values` attribute as `null`

Comment: Your subquery is not the correct way to get the most common value for each criteria ID.

Comment: ill retest tomorrow but it should be. it selects values ordered than slices the top? @Barmar

Comment: You should be using `RIGHT JOIN` if the missing rows are in `top_trends`. `LEFT JOIN` would be appropriate if the missing rows are in `search_criteria`.

Comment: There's no slicing. It picks a random value in each group, then orders by that.

Comment: @Barmar then ill add a DESC clause to the order by?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you order, it's still picking a random value for each group.

Comment: @Barmar im going to sleep ill review this tomorrow if you have any good answers for me to look at in the morning thatd be great. You understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446368/sql-returning-the-most-common-value-for-each-person for how to get the most common value in a group.

Comment: This problem is unrelated to the problem in your question. The answer to that is to switch the order of the `LEFT JOIN` or change it to `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is used when there are rows in the left table that have no match in the right table. Since the missing rows in your case are in `top_trends`, that should be the right table of the `LEFT JOIN`. So switch the order of the join.

```
select
  x.value as `values`
  , sc.id as id
  , sc.title
  , sc.created_at
  , sc.updated_at
  , x.criteria_id as search_category_id 
from search_criterias sc 
left join
  ( 
    select
      criteria_id
      , `value` 
    from
      top_trends 
    group by
      `criteria_id` 
    order by
      `value`
  ) x 
    on sc.id = x.criteria_id 
group bysc.id
```