# Select most frequent value from a group by function - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using Sequel Pro on a Mac and have a table like this:

```
Table1
a        b
Blah     5
Blah     5
Smoog    5
Choop    7
Choop    7
Choop    7
Smap     7
Smap     7
Tweep    11
Tweep    11
Florg    11
```

And I'm running this query:

```
Select "MOST FREQUENT OCCURRENCE"(a), b 
From Table1
Group by b
```

What would be the operator I put in for the "MOST FREQUENT OCCURRENCE" part? Basically what I am trying to do is figure out which "a" occurs most often with each "b". The output should look like:

```
"MOST FREQUENT OCCURRENCE"(a)    b
Blah                             5
Choop                            7
Tweep                            11
```

Thank you!

Comment: you are trying to get the first and the last item in the database? not sure I followed

Comment: I think you would just want a count(a) and order by the count DESC

Comment: This table has no key. This is a problem.

Comment: Are these the lyrics to the UK's next Eurovision entry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT most frequent by group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407723/mysql-select-most-frequent-by-group)

Answer (score 2):

Not the prettiest query I've seen, but it works. Keep in mind that it can be slow for large sets of data. Any kind of count typically is.

```
SELECT cnts1.a AS a, cnts1.b AS b FROM 
(SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) cnt 
        FROM Table1 t1 
        GROUP BY a, b
      ) AS cnts1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) cnt 
        FROM Table1 t1 
        GROUP BY a, b
      ) AS cnts2
ON cnts1.b = cnts2.b
AND cnts1.cnt < cnts2.cnt
WHERE cnts2.a IS NULL
```

#### Edit:

For the very duplication-unfriendly there is this other alternative which performs the counting only once. Instead of calculating the count of occurrences for each `a`, then seeing which `a` has the maximum count, it calculates for each `a` a string which is composed of the count of occurrences plus the value of `a` itself. After that you get the maximum string, from which the value of `a` is extracted.

Since the count must be padded with zeroes when constructing the string there is a limit to the maximum amount of occurrences that this query can handle, in the example being 99999 (padding to 5 digits).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(cnta, 6) AS a, b
FROM (SELECT b, MAX(cnta) cnta
      FROM (SELECT b, CONCAT(LPAD(COUNT(*), 5, '0'), a) cnta
            FROM table1
            GROUP BY a, b
            ) cnts
      GROUP BY b
      ) maxcnts
```